# Integrating Java Web Start jar with web app

Tags: java, deployment, war, java-web-start, ear

I have a  web application, which does file transfer via applet.

For more security reasons, I am planning to do encryption on the files being sent from my app. For that purpose, I wish to integrate java web start program, I will have the RSA encryption logic written as a part of the web start jar.

I have created a separate web start project (WAR), and am able to launch the jar & perform the required encryption.

My components for web start project are:

1. main class - Encryption.java (Logic for encryption)
2. Deployment Descriptor - web.xml
3. Servlet    - where am setting the response content type as `application/x-java-jnlp-file`
4. JNLP file(Rendered as jsp)

I have a signed jar created with the main class file, and it works when i add it as a part of my independent WAR.

But when I merge with my web app. (I added the web start jar as a part of my ear lib folder), am unable to launch it, & that  shows "Unable to load resource: "

```
Exception got: com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: 
  Wrapped exception : java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP file must have at least one entry
```

Is there any format I need to follow to make this jar reference work?

Am much new to Web start, so looking forward for your inputs on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> (I added the web start jar as a part of my ear lib folder),..

I am not sure, but that sounds like a path for a web app. to put its own APIs.  If such it will not be a path accessible through an URL in the browser, nor to a JWS client that is trying to open it.

For each jar in your desktop app.:

1. Put them in a place that is accessible to a browser. E.G. I use `pscode.org/lib/`.
2. Then *check* the resource path using either of:

   1. By putting the resolved URL of the Jar in the address bar of the browser and attempting to fetch it.
   2. Use [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) which does that & more in a single check.